# Why is the Hot Network Questions page not responsive?

Tags: support, mobile-web, stackexchange.com, responsive-design

I browse the hot network questions every day and for years I've been wondering why every individual Stack Exchange site has a mobile version, but [the hot network questions page](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) is not responsive.

Why is it like this? Seems like it should be fairly trivial to enable.

Comment: the migration to responsiveness is a work in progress. That page is not high on the list specially as there are signs the whole stackexchange.com will get a make over and then that page might be gone or morphed into  something different

Comment: @rene it's not about responsive design. se.com never had mobile theme.

Comment: @Shadow9 huh? That doesn't make sense. Responisveness has nothing to do with a mobile theme, at least not in my book. A responsive design is beneficial on different screen sizes, mobile or not.

Comment: @rene from the wording of the question here sounds like OP is expecting a "mobile" link in the footer of se.com and such thing simply does not exist. "mobile version" isn't about the responsive design, which doesn't really need whole new "version", or theme.