# Question title text too big?

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, responsive-design

[image]

The question title text seems quite massive in comparison to the rest of the page. I am on mobile. Maybe we can make this a bit smaller?

Details of my phone:

- Running Chrome on Android

Comment: Related: [Add mobile view to hot questions list in stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342888/295232)

Comment: What browser/OS? No repro on iOS Chrome.

Comment: No repro, something on your side is just different, we can't really know.

Comment: It is [indeed too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIGvq.png) (on my device too) compared to the size of the tags _and_ the size of question titles [on the real-time tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAAhR.png). Personally, I don't mind it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me this looks perfectly acceptable. Perhaps some of your phone's settings are off? You should include details like that in your report.

[image: Screenshot of stackexchange.com]

Running Chrome on Android.

Answer (score 2):

You have text scaling of more than 100%, hence you see bigger text. I was able to reproduce your screenshot when changing it, e.g. to 150%.

To reach it, open the app settings, then under Advanced, tap Accessibility:

[image: mobile chrome settings]

Then slide the "Text scaling" bar back to 100%, and after reload you'll see the text in the normal size again.

[image: Text scaling at more than 100%]

Comment: My text scaling is 100%

Comment: @DialFrost well, so at some lower level, e.g. system settings.